# How to forward traffic from domain in route53 to a pod using nginx ingress?

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, kubernetes, grafana, amazon-route53

I  deployed grafana using helm and now it is running in pod. I can access it if I proxy port 3000 to my laptop. 
Im trying to point a domain `grafana.something.com` to that pod so I can access it externally.
I have a domain in route53 that I can attach to a loadbalancer (Application Load Balancer, Network Load Balancer, Classic Load Balancer). That load balancer can forward traffic from port 80 to port 80 to a group of nodes (Let's leave port 443 for later).
I'm really struggling with setting this up. Im sure there is something missing but I don't know what.

Basic diagram would look like this I imagine.

Internet
↓↓
Domain in route53 (grafana.something.com)

↓↓
Loadbalancer 80 to 80 (Application Load Balancer, Network Load Balancer, Classic Load Balancer)
I guess that LB would forward traffic to port 80 to the below Ingress Controllers (Created when Grafana was deployed using Helm)

↓↓
Group of EKS worker nodes
↓↓
Ingress resource ?????
↓↓
Ingress Controllers - Created when Grafana was deployed using Helm in namespace test.

`kubectl get svc grafana -n test`

`grafana     Type:ClusterIP ClusterIP:10.x.x.x  Port:80/TCP`

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: 
  labels:
    app: grafana
    chart: grafana-
    heritage: Tiller
    release: grafana-release
  name: grafana
  namespace: test
  resourceVersion: "xxxx"
  selfLink: 
  uid: 
spec:
  clusterIP: 10.x.x.x
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 3000
  selector:
    app: grafana
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: ClusterIP
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```

↓↓
Pod Grafana is listening on port 3000. I can access it successfully after proxying to my laptop port 3000.

Comment: Do you have an Ingress Controller installed? What you're showing is a `Service` (https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/) which is different from an `Ingress` (https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/)

Comment: Looks like I don't have one. The basic ingress would look like that I understand. 
It would forward traffic from grafana.something.com to the service I already have.

apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: grafana-test-ingress-controller
spec:
  rules:
  - host: grafana.something.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: grafana # This is the app: grafana from the service
          servicePort: 80 #This is the port of the app: grafana service

Would the ingress be between the Service and the route53domain/Loadbalancer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given that it seems you don't have an [Ingress Controller](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress-controllers/) installed, if you have the aws cloud-provider configured in your K8S cluster you can follow [this guide](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/#using-helm) to install the Nginx Ingress controller using Helm.

By the end of the guide you should have a load balancer created for your ingress controller, point your Route53 record to it and create an Ingress that uses your grafana service. Example:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/app-root: /
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/enable-access-log: "true"
  name: grafana-ingress
  namespace: test
spec:
  rules:
  - host: grafana.something.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: grafana
          servicePort: 80
        path: /
```

The final traffic path would be:

```
Route53 -> ELB -> Ingress -> Service -> Pods
```

Comment: It worked! Turns out I already had an ingress so I only followed the helm Nginx Ingress controller and after pointing out the domain it worked. Thank you. I need to put this on to a diagram so I can understand.

I installed nginx with defaults and it worked but how does it know where to forward grafana.something.com, does it automatically detects the ingress I created? The nginx seems to have those ports 80:31092/TCP,443:30264/TCP so how does this magic work ?

Comment: When you create an Ingress the chosen Ingress Controller detects it and configures the backend depending on the configuration. I don't know 100% the configuration it places but given is nginx it must add a server block with the configured host, nginx takes care of the rest. The ports 31092 and 30264 you're seeing are the ports exposed in the kubernetes nodes for the loadbalancer to be able to forward traffic to the nginx pods. The 80 and 443 are the listener ports of your LB.

Answer (score 1):

**Adding 2 important suggestions here.**

1 ) Following [improvements to the ingress api in kubernetes 1.18](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2020/04/02/improvements-to-the-ingress-api-in-kubernetes-1.18/) -
a new `ingressClassName` field has been added to the Ingress spec that is used to reference the IngressClass that should be used to implement this Ingress. 
**Please consider to switch to `ingressClassName` field instead of the `kubernetes.io/ingress.class` annotation**:

```
kind: Ingress
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
metadata:
  name: grafana-ingress
  namespace: test
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx # <-- Here
  rules:
    - host: grafana.something.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            backend:
              serviceName: grafana
              servicePort: 80
```

2 ) **Consider using [External-DNS](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/external-dns)** for the integration between external DNS servers (Check [this](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/external-dns/blob/master/docs/tutorials/aws.md) example on AWS Route53) and the Kubernetes Ingresses / Services.